# Syntax error in Update Statement ASP Classic

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, sql-update

I am having the syntax error in my code on a update statement, after reading multiple posts about it I cant figure out what is causing the error.

The code is as follows:

```
if request.querystring("do")="customer" then

    New_customer = request.Form("customer")

    openconn con

    sSQL="SELECT RelationNumber FROM Relations WHERE RelationName='" & New_customer & "'"
    set rst = con.execute(sSQL)

        if rst.EOF then 
            response.write "No relation found"

        else
            Relationnumber_update = rst("RelationNumber")

            sSQL2="SELECT Number FROM Orders WHERE Relation=" & Relationnumber_update & ""          
            set rst2 = con.execute(sSQL2)

                if rst2.EOF then                        
                    response.write("No order number found!")
                else
                    if Relationnumber_update <> 1000 then
                        Ordernumber_update = rst2("Nummer")

                        sSQL3="UPDATE Bookings SET Order=" & Ordernumber_update & " WHERE ID=" & request("ID")
                        con.execute(sSQL3)

                    else
                        response.write("Order number 1000 is not allowed!")
                    end if
                end if
        end if

    closeconn con

    response.redirect("myPage.asp?action=page")
    response.end

end if
```

The error happens on the line: `sSQL3="UPDATE Bookings SET Order=" & Ordernumber_update & " WHERE ID=" & request("ID")`

**Things to know:**

- The request queriestring is from the form where the user can choose a customer in a dropdown list. See code: `<form name="ChangeCustomer" method="post" action="myPage.asp?action=page&do=customer&ID=<%=rst("ID")%>" style="display:inline">`
- The rst from ID is from a select statement before which works since I used in also in other code in the same way (that does work).
- The openconn con is a function for accessing my database (it works, same reason as above)
- Eacht select statement in this code has been tested for its output in a response.write. All the results that came out were the expected ones.

**Short description of what happens in the code above**

1. A user changes the customer in the form (with a dropdown menu) and presses save (submit).
2. On submit the queriestring is launched, this was tested if the code actually comes to this and it does.
3. The chosen customer is saved in the var `New_customer`.
4. The relation number that matches the customer name is retrieved with the first select statement.
5. The right relation number is being put into the var `Relationnumber_update`
6. In the second query the right number is being searched for that equals the relation number.
7. A if/then follows which makes sure the Relationnumber_update is not equal to 1000 (no updates should be done on this number)
8. If its not equal to 1000 then the found order number (second select statement) is stored in the var `ordernumber_update`
9. The update statement follows where Order field in the bookings table is being updated with the found ordernumber.
10. In the end (after the if) the connection is being closed and the page is being 'refreshed'.

For some reasson I am getting the syntax error on my update statement but I have no clue why. I checked the data types of the Number field in the orders table, the Relationnumber from the Relations table and the Order field in the bookings table, they are all of type number/int.

I also tried to update with a set number directly in the update statement instead of the ordernumber_update var (like so: `sSQL3="UPDATE Bookings SET Order=6477 WHERE ID=" & request("ID")`) but this gives the same error..

Comment: Order is reserved word ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx#daidxsqln_p ) Either bracket [Order] or alias.

Comment: This typo ("Nummer") must be corrected:   Ordernumber_update = rst2("Number")

Comment: When you're debugging SQL within classic asp it often helps to use `response.write sSQL` so you can see the actual query which is falling over

Comment: You wrote a lot but not a) sql data type for ID column b) current value of request("ID")

Comment: @Fionnuala This was indeed the issue. Saw it 5 min after I posted the question in here, thank you anyway;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. Read about Sql Injections
2. To debug sql statement "live", use

   ```
   sSQL3="UPDATE Bookings ...
   Response.Write(sSQL3)
   'con.execute(sSQL3) -- comment it out
   ```

   run page, and test resulted sql query against database
3. If ID has string datatype (char, varchar, etc) then you should quote its value using '...'

P.S.

Use [Order] to deal with reserved words.

Comment: 1. I did, just didnt implemented it yet because this is a test version. The live version will have a sql protect function on all the inputs (which filters <>^& etc out) and in the live version I am using parameters. 2. I did for all my queries. Used response.write for all the queries. It all came out fine. 3. All data types were checked like I also mentioned in the original post. General: Mistake was I was using the reserved word Order, the error gave me a syntax error but it didn't showed me on what. Realized later that it was Order (overlooked it). Thank you anyway for the comment!

Comment: Great! What about #2? Can you share its output?

Comment: Pressed enter to early;)

Comment: Ok then use [Order] to deal with reserved words.

Comment: Yep done that and it works now, thank you! About the typo, I translated everything into English so missed that one (nummer --> number)  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the reserve words of database management system.
Here you are using `Order`, which is a reserved one.

So use this if you using **MySQL**:

```
sSQL3="UPDATE Bookings SET `Order`=" & Ordernumber_update & " WHERE ID=" & request("ID") &";"
```

Or in case of **SQL Server**:

```
sSQL3="UPDATE Bookings SET [Order]=" & Ordernumber_update & " WHERE ID=" & request("ID") &";"
```

Hope this will help others also. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Use bracketes aound [Order], not single quotes. And don't use reserved words for your field names. Jus sayin'.

Comment: That is not single quote. its backtick (grave), which perfectly works for MySQL.